# Google Places API: how to search by type and location in Python

Tags: python, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm following the example I found on the [main page](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python) of GitHub relative to `googlemaps` and I'm writing my own code in order to retrieve all cinemas from a specific area.

The code is this:

```
import googlemaps

gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key='MyGoogleKey')

search_loction = gmaps.location('40.714224, -73.961452').type('movie_theater')
print (search_loction)
```

It returns me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GoogleMap.py", line 5, in <module>
    search_loction = gmaps.location('40.714224, -73.961452')
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'location'
```

If I follow the guide, yes, the attribute `[location]` is allowed 
[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not know this library but should you not be using `gmaps.places(...)` with the location as a parameter?

Comment: From my understanding this is what the picture says, let me try using places

Comment: @MrUpsidown, your suggestion was right, post it as an answer so I can label it as the right reply

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-python/docs/), you should use

`gmaps.places(...)` with the `location` as a parameter.

Something like

`gmaps.places(location=(lat,lng), type="movie_theater")`